# Missing filter option in Prompt flow tool "Index Lookup"

Tags: azure, azure-promptflow

I had to switch to the new preview tool "Index Lookup" because the outdated "Vector DB Lookup" no longer appears in my tool list. Unfortunately, it is no longer possible to specify a filter for the Azure AI search. Does anyone know whether the option still exists or how it could be solved differently?

I can't find the setting and there's nothing in the documentation about it.